# Partitioning Windows disks rendered Mac OS unbootable

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, mac, partitioning, boot-camp

I installed Windows 10 with the help of Bootcamp, by partitioning around 40 GB of free Space from the 256 GB SSD in my MacBook Pro.

However, I was running out of free disk Space, so I rebooted into Mac OS to resize the partition. This gave me around 40 GB extra disk Space. Once back into Windows I used a Third party Application for merging the free Space With the Bootcamp partition. This required me to move to partitions on the disk to be able to merge them.

However, this operation resulted in the computer now not able to boot back into Mac OS. The Mac OS boot disk is not showing during startup, but the disk Applications in Windows sees the partition as "unidentified" and 0 B free of 158 GB.

As far as I can understand, the Mac OS disk still exists, but the Mac cannot recognize it. Is there some way to recover this disk as a bootable disk?

I can't reinstall Mac OS either, because it only sees the bootcamp disk, and the disk is locked. Am I stuck in Windows 10 forever?

Comment: You broke the golden rule: never touch the partitioning from within Windows, it simply doesn't understand how it's being fooled into thinking it's in charge. [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) may be able to fix it.

Comment: A BCDeditor may help

Comment: @Tetsujin even with such tools it can be quite dangerous to move partitions. Shrinking and growing usually are less of a problem.

Comment: @Seth - doing anything like this shouldn't be undertaken without a solid backup anyway, so worst-case scenario is just nuke, pave & start over. Having said that I've known HDM to fix drives nothing else would & never known it to break anything.

Comment: @Tetsujin Pricy software just to try out when I don't know how to use the software at all. Easiest would be to reinstall the Whole computer, but as I just stated in the original post, the disk is locked and reinstalling Mac OS not an option.

Comment: tbh, if you didn't bother reading far enough down the page to discover it has a 10-day free trial, then attempting to do it "for free" is a bit like this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319880/how-can-i-make-my-mac-partition-bootable-again - see how you get on.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry I missed that part!